# Updating an array for jQuery fade in and fade out with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fade

I am trying to create a fade in/out effect with a array elements that change with time. The array will be updated by a function that fetches the array items from a external source on an hourly basis.

The problem I am having is a seamless integration into jQuery fade in/fade out function.

Currently, I have tried to use *setInterval* but I don't think that's the best approach. The fading elements start overlapping with each reiteration of the entire function.

Here's what I've been working on:
https://jsfiddle.net/gan5dt1n/

```
var h = document.createElement('html');

function horofunc() {
  item1 = new Date();
  item2 = new Date().getHours();
  item3 = new Date().getMinutes();
  item4 = new Date().getSeconds();
  item5 = "Line 5";
  dhsplit = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5];
  console.log(dhsplit)

  for (i = 0; i < dhsplit.length - 1; i++) {
    var line = document.createElement("div");
    line.className = "line";
    var node = document.createTextNode(dhsplit[i]);
    line.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("scope");
    element.appendChild(line);
  }

}


function horosdisp() {
  $(function() {
    $('#scope div:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#scope :first-child').fadeOut(200)
          .next('div');
        $('#scope :first-child').fadeOut(200)
          .next('div').fadeIn(200);
        $('#scope :first-child').fadeOut(200)
          .next('div').end().appendTo('#scope');
      },
      1500);
  });
}


horofunc();
horosdisp();
setInterval(horofunc, 10000); //0*60*6);
setInterval(horosdisp, 5000);
```

I am a total beginner in JS and I realise the solution could be obvious.
The code might be very messy, but at the moment I am just trying to stitch things together so it works. Please forgive any redundancies in the code, I am still learning the basics of JS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the contents in the scope element before you push new values into the array. `setInterval` in the `horosdisp` function is not necessary as you are already doing it while calling the function and try adjusting the fadeOut intervals and setInterval milliseconds so that the transition looks smooth.

```
var h = document.createElement('html');

function horofunc() {
var element = document.getElementById("scope");
element.innerHTML='';
  item1 = new Date();
  item2 = new Date().getHours();
  item3 = new Date().getMinutes();
  item4 = new Date().getSeconds();
  item5 = "Line 5";
  dhsplit = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5];
  console.log(dhsplit)

  for (i = 0; i < dhsplit.length - 1; i++) {
    var line = document.createElement("div");
    line.className = "line";
    var node = document.createTextNode(dhsplit[i]);
    line.appendChild(node);

    element.appendChild(line);

  }

}


function horosdisp() {
   $(function() {
    $('#scope div:gt(0)').hide();

        $('#scope :first-child').fadeOut(200)
          .next('div');
        $('#scope :first-child').fadeOut(200)
          .next('div').fadeIn(200);
        $('#scope :first-child').fadeOut(200)
          .next('div').end().appendTo('#scope');
      }
  );
}


horofunc();
horosdisp();
setInterval(horofunc, 3600); //0*60*6);
setInterval(horosdisp, 1200);
```

Didn't try it but the above changes should work.
Happy learning.

Comment: I tried to adjust the timings but I still get glitches i.e. the updated items from the array pop up and disappear immediately without the fade effect.